# For loop should loop 9 times, instead loops once

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code should be taking two numbers from the user and then state which number is higher, 9 times, thus "counter <10 " except it only takes the two numbers once, and then the loop is finished. I thought I could increment the loop by using "counter=counter +1" in my loop, but it doesnt seem to work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
counter = 0
for counter in range(counter < 10):
    num1 = float(input("Enter number 1: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter number 2: "))
    if num1 > num2:
        print(num1)
    else:
        print(num2)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 6):

`counter < 10` returns `True` which is equal to `1`:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> counter < 10
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

In turn, `range(1)` yields `0` (single item):

```
>>> list(range(counter < 10))
[0]
```

That's why it loop once.

---

Instead of `range(counter < 10)`, you should use `range(9)`. You don't need to declare `counter = 0` and to increment yourself `counter = counter + 1`. `for` statement take care of it:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

`counter<10` is equivalent to 1. That is why, the loop runs just once ( **range(1) = {0}** ).

You can use either :

```
for counter in range(10):
    ...
```

or

```
counter = 0
while( counter<10 ):
    ...
    counter+=1
```

for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear to you, the expression within the brackets are evaluated at first place. If you want to use `for`, then you need to pass a sequence, over which the `for` will loop through. The `range()` is used to generate the sequence . But here you are passing `(count < 10)` to `range()`, which is a condition. So while evaluated, it returns `True` since `counter` is 0 (initialized in the first line) and is less than 10. And this returned `True` is equivalent to `1`, so the rest goes as described by falsetru

If you want to pass a condition, then you should use `while` loop, instead of `for`. In `for`, you don't even need to initialize the variable `counter` separately. If you write :-

```
for counter in range(9):
```

this will initialize `counter` variable and it would be incremented in each iteration.

For your question you can use either of the following:-

```
for counter in range(9):
    # No need to initialize counter
    do_stuff
```

or

```
# Initialize counter
counter = 0
while(counter <10):
    do_stuff
```